# CakePHP custom setFlash

Tags: php, cakephp

I've read on the CakePHP Book that you can define your own custom setFlash messages using an element... but what I would I put inside the element and how would I pass different content.

So for example two different messages:

```
<div id="flashMessage" class="message">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Please correct the errors</p>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="flashMessage" class="announcement message">
    <div class="content">
        <h3>Announcement</h3>
        <p>You have earned a new achievement</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

So as you can see I want to define a wrapper div and a content div and then also pass in an additional class if need be dependant on the kind of message and also show different content such as just a paragraph or a header and a paragraph.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have two elements:

myflash.ctp

```
<div id="flashMessage" class="message">
    <div class="content">
        <p><? echo $message ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

announcement.ctp

```
<div id="flashMessage" class="announcement message">
    <div class="content">
        <h3>Announcement</h3>
        <p><? echo $message ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then:

```
$this->Session->setFlash($message,'myflash or announcement');
```

**or** one element:
myflash.ctp

```
<div id="flashMessage" class="<? echo (isset($myclass)?$myclass.' ':'') ?>message">
 <div class="content">
  <? echo (isset($header)?'<h3>' . $header.'</h3>':'') ?>
   <p><? echo $message ?></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

and at your controller:

```
$this->Session->setFlash($message,'myflash',array('myclass'=>'announcement','header'=>'Announcement');
```

Comment: What if I wanted to tailor it all from the setFlash as I may want to create new classes on the fly and add multiple paragraphs and/or change the header.